# ZIP 2.0 decryption produces unexpected results

Tags: c, zip

I am trying to implement the 'Traditional PKWARE Decryption' described in Section 6.1 of the .ZIP File Format Specification (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), but the results are not as expected.

For testing, I am using a small text file zipped with TUGZip using no compression.

The CRC-32 of the original file is **0x7259B728**.

The 12 byte 'encryption header' in the .ZIP file contains `E6-8B-FE-EB-40-28-E1-55-4E-44-28-E0`

The 'password' is `61-7A-62-79-63` (azbyc).

Encryption header after decryption contains `C3-7D-EE-4C-11-B3-39-A3-97-55-21-B3`

Section 6.1.6 of the specification says:

*"After the header is decrypted, the last 1 or 2 bytes in Buffer should be the high-order word/byte of the CRC for the file being decrypted ...."*

so I would expect 0x72, but I get 0xB3.

As far as I can tell, I followed the spec exactly, but I am still quite new to C so I recreated the program in C#, and got the same results. I'm obviously missing or misunderstanding something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**zip.c**

```
//struct ZIP_INFO contains member 'uint32_t *keys'
//
//At initialisation, the values are:
//keys[0] = 0x12345678
//keys[1] = 0x23456789
//keys[2] = 0x34567890

unsigned char zip_decrypt_byte(uint32_t *keys)
{
    uint16_t u = (uint16_t)((keys[2] & 0xFFFF) | 0x02);
    return (unsigned char)(((u * (u ^ 0x01)) >> 8) & 0xFF);
}

void zip_decrypt_bytes(ZIP_INFO *info, unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *u = buf;
    while (len--)
    {
        *u ^= zip_decrypt_byte(info->keys);
        zip_update_keys(info->keys, u++);
    }
}

void zip_set_password(ZIP_INFO *info, unsigned char *password, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *u = password;
    while (len--)
        zip_update_keys(info->keys, u++);
}

void zip_update_keys(uint32_t *keys, unsigned char *c)
{
    unsigned char u;
    keys[0] = crc_32(keys[0], c, 1);
    keys[1] += (keys[0] & 0xFF);
    keys[1] = ((keys[1] * 134775813) + 1);
    u = (unsigned char)((keys[1] >> 24) & 0xFF);
    keys[2] = crc_32(keys[2], &u, 1);
}
```

**crc.c**

```
static uint32_t crc_table[256];

uint32_t crc_32(uint32_t crc, unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *p;
    crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    p = buf;
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc_table[((crc ^ *p++) & 0xFF)] ^ (crc >> 8));
    return (crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

void crc_initialise()
{
    uint32_t u0, u1, u2;
    for (u0 = 0; u0 < 256; u0++)
    {
        u1 = u0;
        for (u2 = 0; u2 < 8; u2++)
        {
            if (u1 & 0x01)
                u1 = ((u1 >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320);
            else
                u1 >>= 1;
        }
        crc_table[u0] = u1;
    }
}
```

**Contents of *'test.zip'***

> 50-4B-03-04-14-00-01-00-00-00-F9-1E-55-47-28-B7-59-72-2B-00-00-00-1F-00-00-00-08-00-00-00-74-65-78-74-2E-74-78-74-E6-8B-FE-EB-40-28-E1-55-4E-44-28-E0-15-8E-13-49-CD-B0-B7-E4-43-40-9D-BA-5D-41-A8-BD-EA-47-07-AD-0E-4A-2F-BA-BD-1F-55-94-D3-6E-77-50-4B-01-02-14-00-14-00-01-00-00-00-F9-1E-55-47-28-B7-59-72-2B-00-00-00-1F-00-00-00-08-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-74-65-78-74-2E-74-78-74-50-4B-05-06-00-00-00-00-01-00-01-00-36-00-00-00-51-00-00-00-00-00